# rxjava drops downstream results

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a rx method to make an api call, and the caller of this method could happen multiple time in a very short time. So the rx method would be

```
public void apiCallWithRx() {
    apiService.makeApiCall()
        .subscribeOn(Schecdulars.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainTread())
        .subscribe(
           // onNext
           new onConsume(),
          // onError
           new onConsume(),

         );
}
```

The caller method could call this apiCallWithRx multiple times in a short time..
But the problem is that i sometimes couldnt get response from downtream when calling from second time, or any specific time. Neither onNext, onError or onComplete is called.
I was wondering, is this because of buffer or backpressure..
Tried with rxjava1 and rxjava2, they are same.

I would be much appreciated for any advice.

**UPDATE 1**

I didnt see any backpressure exception, so it couldnt be a backpressure issue.

**UPDATE 2**

Please ignore the detail, the Rx code works most of the time. I just omitted some code for illustration purpose

**UPDATE 3**

I have a BlockingQueue in the background, so this rx method is actually called when there is an available data in the queue. The data can be added into the queue at anytime. And *this rx method is **not** called asynchronously*, since this method is called only after the first response and then check the queue, if there is a data, then we send second api request.

Comment: Using a BlockingQueue with RxJava is prone to deadlocks. You likely need an UnicastSubject to buffer data until the downstream can consume it.

Comment: @akamokd  The apiCallWithRx() method is called from UI thread on android, so the ExecutorService is fetching data from BlockingQueue in background thread, and the data is passed onto UI thread, and triggered  apiCallWithRx() method on UI thread. And it will check the blockingqueue to get the next request data whenever we get the api response from server for previous request data. So the api call and BlockingQueue are pretty separated, I dont think there is a deadlock here

Answer (score 0):

`Observable` is lazy by default and you must `subscribe` to it for the `Observable` to run.

Comment: yeah, we have that code, for illustration purpose, its omitted.

Comment: Your code uses the version of `subscribe` that triggers the observable but ignores all events.

Comment: thats code is omitted for illustration purpose, real code has that, just added onNext, onError

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why in RxJava2 **subscribeOn** and **observerOn** operator can be used without specify the Thread where it must be executed.

But at least in RxJava1 if you use those operators you run it asynchronously and then you have to wait in the execution to get the result.

Check this test

```
@Test
public void testObservableAsync() throws InterruptedException {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.from(numbers)
            .doOnNext(increaseTotalItemsEmitted())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(number -> System.out.println("Items emitted:" + total));
    System.out.println("I finish before the observable finish.  Items emitted:" + total);
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see another examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java

Comment: Updated question, I use a BlockingQueue to make sure that the rx method is called sequentially